# Scrollable blockquote

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

Is it possible to have a scrollable blockquote? Like a `<textarea>`, Just vertical without any horizontal.

Comment: WTF is this good for?

Comment: @John in my case it would be for quoting long texts or codes without disrupting too much the Q&A layout.

Comment: Sounds like it's not good for SO, @Cawas.

Comment: But, why not @John? Maybe you could provide a better answer, I'd love to hear good reasons to "why not".

Comment: You know brevity and wit, @Cawas? You failed, if you quote long texts/codes. Most of the time (i.e. in 99.999999999% of the cases) you do not need to do it. If you really need, post the code outside SO and link to it.

Comment: @John don't exaggerate. You just admitted it I may "really need it" and then I should link to outside. Why not having it in here?

Comment: Why don't you just properly style the code you post?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers/7705#7705 - http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/incomplete.html

Comment: @John and @voyager, about the meta link, If I were to read and accept only that Jeff's answer I'd be doing it completely out of the context of the whole question, which is voted up for doing exactly what I wanted to do here. There's even a Skeet's comment right below it approving the "folding" of information that I'm suggesting here. I would even mark this question as a duplicate of that now.

Comment: No idea what you tried to do with the false "duplicate", but I rolled it back.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is more than 4 years old. I'm pretty sure it made more sense back then, but I do agree it's not such a "duplicate" anymore! ;) Heck, I've never seen [a Jeff's post downvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7705/143411) that much (22 there)! :-o

Comment: Yeah, that's the price for declining a popular request... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your text within a `<pre> .. </pre>` block, it will cause a scrollable text window to appear after about a dozen lines.

You can also indent each line four spaces to create a colorized "code sample" which will create the same scrollable window (with "prettify" code colorization). Or you can just hit the 'Code Sample' at the top of the editor.

> [image]

The text will be in a mono-space font. There is no way to create a scrollable window using the  *literal* `'Blockquote <blockquote> Ctrl-Q'` formatting.

Comment: I forgot to say that I was hoping for vertical scrolling with no horizontal. But thanks for the answer! ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry. No can do.

Comment: Oh, so maybe I should suggest as a new feature?

Comment: Hey I recognize that image...

Comment: I guess this is answered on the comment.