# Add Expanders to markdown so users can hide "More Info" text

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Expand/Collapse More/Less Info buttons are a common concept across the web - wouldn't adding this feature make it easier for users to read those long-text examples?

I am aware that there is the spoiler markdown, but that doesn't collapse down the space, so misses the point of making the rest of it easier to read.

When writing a question or an answer there is often the case where I would like to provide extra information to help the OP or answerers if they need it.
A perfect example would be providing the SQL for the database schema to recreate your problem when posting a question on StackOverflow. Most users won't need to see it when reading your question, unless they have access to a database and want to recreate it. But it is useful info if it is required.
But the problem is this SQL may take up a lot of space. Maybe 100 lines of SQL with a 2 line question at the end. I think this "WALL OF TEXT" turns off a lot of readers.

Some example posts I think could do with hiding text unless required:
[Returning top results for events in a competition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731422/returning-top-results-for-events-in-a-competition/24524300#24524300) (the example that led me here)
[Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658) (here they have used headers to try and break up the wall of text - good idea, but I think expander would also work)
..

Comment: GitHub [supports](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-collapsed-sections) it; why not SE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrollable blockquote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41219/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303150/282094 **or** https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261082/282094  
- on sites that support MathJax there is equation numbering (that jumps to the equation), I think it also works for chapters and sections (or it could be implemented at SE):  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by mtk, indeed the markdown processor is an external dependency. However the only output from the processor is markup - the css/js used to display and post-process the markup is entirely under SE's control. This could include javascript to auto-shrink and expand on click, binding to the selector `.spoiler`.

If you hadn't worked it out, I would also like to see this implemented. :D

Answer (score 1):

The markdown used by SO is not a homegrown formatter. As given on [edit-help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), they have reused it from here

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

So, probably this request should be raised to the actual project-team or maybe someone from SO-team can raise it.

Hope this helps