# Collapse code snippets in answers

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I've just answered a question in SO where I had to post four snippets of XML (yes, it was a JavaEE question, how did you guess?)

I made an effort to keep the snippets short and meaningful, but all this code can clutter the visuals of the page, and moves attention away from the rest of the answer.

The site can already detect which parts of the question or answer are code, and paints them in a different font and background. What if it could also add a small toggle button that hides/display each snippet of code?

An example. Displayed: [image: A crudely drawn image of a widget whose purpose is to collapse a block of code, complete with an arrow pointing to this widget and a description "button to hide snippet" of said widget.]

Hidden: [image: The same widget as before, only this time it is in a different state and the associated block of code has been truncated according to the requested feature's behaviour. An arrow continues to point at the widget but it is accompanied by another arrow pointing out that an ellipsis (...) symbol should be used to indicate the aforementioned truncation has taken place.]

Please acknowledge my superior Photoshop skillzs.

Comment: It's a bit of a clunkily edited question, but [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers) which asks for code collapse (and then some) has been denied.

Comment: @26: you've inflicted superfluous "u"s on blind people yet again! Why do you hate the blind so?

Comment: @shognine: I appeal to only the most Canadian of blind people. The blind people of lesser countries will have to make do.

Comment: @26: Aye. A thousand apologies. I promise I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Aside: the site does *not* "detect" code, it provides a formatting option for code (well, two one for inline and one for blocks).

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302078/collapsible-code-markup

Answer (score 20):

For the record, this now exists (at least for some languages).

```
<!- begin snippet: js hide: true -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

alert(2+40);

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Note: `<!- begin` should actually be `<!-- begin`, but because of the way HTML-comments work, doing so would not display the above code.

Adding the missing hyphen, it will look like:

```js
alert(2+40);
```

Comment: but what if i want to hide a sample response of some code/command? "Show code snippet" is not what it should say

Comment: @joeybaruch You really should be able to put your own text in there. I think at least that it's obvious it's a dropdown. Then you can name each of the dropdowns something like 'index.html', 'main.css', 'main.js'

Comment: 8 years later, is this really all there is? Is there no generic collapsible block that can be titled as desired?