# Long code in question: Adding a hide/display button

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Many a time and oft there is a real need for long sequences of code, especially stack traces or [error logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/242087/x-over-ssh-to-ubuntu-server). This also happens in other SE sites, TEX being a [good example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12443/optional-but-encouraged-line-break-hfill). Unfortunately, these long code blocks can reduce the readability of the question, and let important non-code text ignored.

Do you think that adding a show\hide (or collapse\expand) button would be a good idea?

**Addendum**

My first idea was to have only a collapse\expand button, but reading the comments and [other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/view-code-in-new-window) made me think that other functionality could be added:

1. Expand\Collapse
2. Copy to clipboard
3. Open in a new window
4. Toggle line numbers on and off - simplifies referring to a specific line in an answer.

[Syntax Highlighter evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/screenshots/) might be a good example.

**UPDATE:**

This is really annoying in Server Fault [questions with long logs or configuration files](https://serverfault.com/questions/252682/resotre-raid-configuration-ubuntu-8-04-server). The question itself virtually undetectable between all the long code snippets.

Comment: Besides the vertically scrolling problem there is also the horizontally scrolling problem. I don't like horizontal scrollbars. It would be great to be able to open large scripts in a separate windows or tabs or scripted windows.

Comment: @Stefan, for new windows see [View code in new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/view-code-in-new-window).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse code snippets in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70885/collapse-code-snippets-in-answers) (and the declined [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: It's not only for code. I can remember of a few times where I wished there was a way to collapse some of the stuff that I was going to write (usually images and graphs, but not only).

Comment: @Borror0, true. (Another example: responses from command line commands might not be too interesting for most readers.) Maybe this could be solved by using [the "spoiler" formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396), if that would not occupy the full height in its hidden state? And then also allows for permanently triggering the visible state (maybe related to [Can we have the spoiler text show on click too?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80867/can-we-have-the-spoiler-text-show-on-click-too)).

Comment: Isn't that specific example too localised for a Q&A site such as Server Fault?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the greasemonkey script that can only expand/collapse code blocks

[Install](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/98152.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/98152) - (only tested on firefox 3.6 and chrome 11 dev)

---

#### Screen shots 1

[image]

#### to

[image]

---

#### Screen shots 2

[image]

#### to

[image]

---

Comment: +1 Truly great hack.