# HTML tag for content toggling, hide/show

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers)

Cannot seem to find such a request, but, I was thinking, it would be nice if there was a feature that allows content toggling.

```
<toggle title="My toggle title">
    <!-- super long content here -->
</toggle>
```

equals

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|               My toggle title              |
|--------------------------------------------|
```

which when **clicked**, displays content within.

Could become useful for community wiki's where you can hide original question, and display list of best answers or something. Cannot find any example thread at the moment, but I've seen some which could use this feature.

Plus, when editing and adding a new question, that doesn't require to start a new question, you hide original, already answered, one.

Could as well be used as an advanced spoiler alert.