# Zooming question content on click

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes people write tons of lines of code and it is very difficult to read by scrolling in small windows. What I am suggesting is to give zoom icon on which if user clicks on content, a popover windows opens (full-screen modal popover) with exact content which is easier to read.

Comment: I rather vote for preventing such big code blocks from being postable.

Comment: Popover windows should be a no-no for any situation. Imagine trying to view the code in a popover when using your iPhone? Urgh, no thanks. If there really *needs* to be lots of code (which I doubt) then hive it off elsewhere (jsfiddle or something). A popover has no benefit here.

Comment: Userscript on Stack Apps: [Click to expand code regions](http://stackapps.com/questions/2574/click-to-expand-code-regions)

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 8):

> Sometimes people writes tons of lines of code

Well. That's the problem, actually.

It is extremely rare for a good question to actually require all that much code. And for the OP of such a question to not format it in such a way that scrolling is not required.

Such questions should be edited so that only relevant code is there.

And if they are just a code dump, they should be closed and eventually deleted.