# Spoilers that unhide on clicking a button/dropdown

Tags: feature-request, design, spoilers

It would be very useful to have a spoiler feature. I am aware of the spoilers already implemented:

> Such as this one!

But I am talking about a button or dropdown that would reveal hidden text.

This would be useful for long answers with multiple headers and could make the site look neater and cleaner.

Comment: Achille Hui actually made one [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/hierarchical-spoilers/13738#13738) that works for MathJax. If you really want, you can use $/text$ to add text. This is limited, though, and only works if the site has MathJax.

Answer (score 8):

Spoilers are obnoxious. *Intentionally* obnoxious - the whole point is to **hide information** on a site dedicated to sharing information.

**They should be used sparingly if at all**.

Making it slightly easier for readers to un-break a post that should never have been broken in the first place is a poor fix. Instead, when you encounter a lengthy post with multiple, critical pieces of information **hidden**, then edit them to be normal text or blockquotes and save future readers the frustration of having to piece together pointlessly-censored text.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to say. What I meant was for an answer with different headings (e.g. where there are different approaches to doing something), to have spoiler headers so that the user can unhide the part of the answer that is relevant to them instead of having to scroll through text they don't need.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers