# Allow folding/collapsing of certain segments of posts

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

A question with attachments, screenshots and/or long code, makes it vertically long and often difficult to read fast.

It would be nice to have a new kind of format, such as 'hideable', with a graphic button or a '+' / '-' sign, so you can add additional details, visible only on a click.

Comment: Similar request just for code blocks [has been declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers). Hopefully, this one will get a second chance.

Comment: I hope not, hopefully this will get enough support!

Comment: Or at least internal links/anchors, so we can (say) use headings to divide up long posts and add direct links to the top.

Comment: As a note, implementing this (which I think would be useful) would negate the need for the existing "spoiler" code. It would also improve it. I think that such spoilers should be gated behind a click anyway, rather than empty space and a hover.

Comment: Related posts: [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5199) and [How to create a collapsable field in a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292552).: