# You should be able to collapse certain parts of posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, design

I wrote a rather long answer today that had many parts to it and it may have actually been confusing to some readers which section started and ended where, and though I tried my best, there was just so much stuff that people could still miss it. So I think that it would be really good if there was a way of collapsing parts of a post, so that there would be a title for that section and then a little arrow which when pressed would reveal the section within it which could contain images and text alike and would just be a way of easily compressing a post and only showing what is necessary and the user wants to see at one time. 
The poster could also choose which parts should be collapsed by default, and which not. This would mostly be useful in answers.

You are currently able to hide certain parts of a post with `>!` but that does not fully collapse the section nor does it work well for large sections because to scroll down you will probably have to allow it to disappear again.

Comment: Related: [Allow folding/collapsing of certain segments of posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271829/allow-folding-collapsing-of-certain-segments-of-posts)

Comment: @Deer actually a duplicate, though I think there is a better one.