# Folding Sections in Answers

Tags: feature-request, markdown, spoilers, stack-snippets

We already have the spoiler formatting

> like this

for information that should be hidden until specifically needed (by hovering), and the code snippet formatting

```js
like this
```

for code that can be revealed and left visible, but when answering questions that ask specifically for a hint, or a direction (e.g. my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42388532/7201281)) it would be very useful to be able to either create a hierarchical spoiler (such that viewing spoiler 3 reveals spoilers 1 and 2 as well), or a non-code snippet (such that the user can expand the entire post without having to use 'Ctrl+A' to view everything inverted), in order to provide the information that the question asks for specifically, while still solving the problem for future visitors who may want more than a hint.

The collapsing is covered in part by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271829), but the idea of hierarchical / sequential spoilers has not been raised / addressed before.

Comment: This sounds like something that very few sites would actually benefit from and that would be rather complicated to enact...

Comment: @Catija The second option seems less complex than code snippets, with about as much applicability as them, but I doubt it would be a high priority in any event - nice to have, though