# Still trying to learn some basic formatting -- can I say "click here to skip this section"?

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I post mainly to Aviation Stack Exchange.  Please let me know if the "chat" feature of ASE, or any other place, would be a better place to ask this question.

I am still in the process of learning some of the basic coding which may be inserted into a Stack Exchange question or answer.

I am in the process of creating a rather lengthy post, of which I suspect some readers may want to skip over some specific sections.

Is there an easy way to insert into my post, some code that says essentially "click here to skip to the next section"?

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid that this isn't possible in the current configuration.

At best, you can use headings to split apart your post into clearly defined sections, so users can easily scroll your post to read relevant parts.

There exists a feature request asking for this ability: [Allow folding/collapsing of certain segments of posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271829/allow-folding-collapsing-of-certain-segments-of-posts). It's several years old; you can find some advice to get attention for it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without). The argument there is kind of weak; a great way to support it would be to make your Aviation post with headings as above, then post an answer to that request explaining in detail how the ability to hide sections would have been useful in that case.

Comment: What the OP asks is basically Fragment identifiers and there is also an open FR on CommonMark for that feature, at least last time I checked. In that specification discussion you can read what is hard about it and why it is unlikely to get done in 6 to 8 weeks. Assuming SE still plans to move to CommonMark.