# Should niche sites be allowed to be multi-lingual?

Tags: discussion, area-51, non-english-speakers, localization, internationalization

I understand why Stack Overflow is English-only, and agree with this, but in [the response from Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/add-meta-tag-to-support-internationalization/7320#7320) to an interesting suggestion from Oscar Reyes, he notes that "for Stack Exchange, this is a different story".

Take for example the [Woodworking and Carpentry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5356/woodworking-and-carpentry) proposal. I would love such a site, but since the jargon is different in each language, I would have a hard time participating in it without the risk of losing one or more fingers due to misunderstanding of some key terminology. On the other hand, it would be a shame if this (maybe not so large) community would be fractioned by language, while we could create some tools to bridge the gap (I can imagine an automatic integration with Wikipedia articles, and their inter-wiki links, for certain key words, e.g. "Take your [chisel (*beitel*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisel) and work on the last part of the [dovetail (*zwaluwstaart*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetail)".

Imagine if we could harvest the power of the multilingual experts by letting the communicate not only in English, but also in other languages with less experienced people. Or all the experts who don't speak English, but are not numerous enough to form separate communities. Could the idea from Oscar, combined with some extra tools, create an environment where they can all contribute?

Comment: I wasn't aware that carpentry was considered a niche... though I suppose they could just make one for themselves.

Comment: Another issue - if the site is _about_ a language, should it be multi-lingual? See, eg, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese/7864#7864

Comment: @bdonlan Yes, the language SEs are multilingual now in the way that they also have additionally english.

Comment: Also there is http://diy.stackexchange.com/ home improvement SE now and unfortunately they didn't include this nice idea. So my fingers are still in danger.